# Error while trying to mimic intersection

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I am trying to mimic the query(for academical purpose)

```
(select course_id from section where semester = 'Spring' and year = 2010) 
intersect
(select course_id from section where semester = 'Fall' and year = 2009)
```

Successfully mimicked with

```
select t.course_id from section t, section s where s.course_id = t.course_id and
s.semester = 'Spring' and s.year = 2010 and t.semester = 'Fall' and t.year = 2009;
```

and when I tried these,

```
select t.course_id from section t, section s where s.course_id = t.course_id and
(s.semester, s.year, t.semester,t.year) in ('Spring',2010,'Fall',2009);
```

> error at the parenthesis after `in` predicate(as per the row and
>   column mentioned in error), error is ORA-00920: invalid relational
>   operator
>   00920. 00000 -  "invalid relational operator"

then I tried

```
select t.course_id from section t, section s where 
s.course_id = t.course_id and (s.semester,s.year) = ('Spring',2010) 
and (t.semester, t.year) in ('Fall',2009);


select t.course_id from section t, section s where 
s.course_id = t.course_id and ((s.semester,s.year) in ('Spring',2010)) 
and ((t.semester, t.year) = ('Fall',2009));
```

with different combination of `in` and `=` getting the same error at parenthesis after the first `in` or `=`

Is there a limit in mentioning attributes for `(..) in/= (...)` or using the same table causes this or some other reason?

using Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all stop using "comma join syntax". It is obsolete and has great successor named `JOIN`. You can read more here: [`INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause).

Second you need to wrap your value with another pair of round brackets:

```
SELECT t.course_id 
FROM section t 
JOIN section s 
  ON s.course_id = t.course_id
WHERE (s.semester, s.year, t.semester,t.year) IN (('Spring',2010,'Fall',2009));
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/162cc/1/0)**</kbd>

You may ask "Why I need extra round brackets?", think about multiple values in `IN` clause:

```
WHERE (col1, col2, col3, col4) IN ((1,2,3,4), (5,6,7,8), (9,10,11,12))
```

Your confusion may be caused by single value like:

```
WHERE col IN (1,2,3);
<=>
WHERE (col) IN ((1), (2), (3));
```

Comment: The comma join, or CROSS JOIN, is not the same as just JOIN.

Comment: @Shredderroy I refer to `from section t, section s where s.course_id = t.course_id ` where join is done in `WHERE` clause. Of course without `WHERE` you will get Cartesian product.

Comment: @lad2025 can you refer any book that provides deep knowledge on SQL, the oracle documentation is too advance for me

Comment: @Sab I would recommend `Oracle Database 12c SQL by Jason Price` and after it `Oracle Database 12c PL/SQL Programming by Michael McLaughlin`